# Two definitions of current operator $J$ equivalent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-hall-effect

I am currently reading David Tong's lecture note on quantum Hall effect. In this note, the current operator $\mathbf J$ is defined in two ways:

1. We define $J= -e\dot{\mathbf x}= (-e/m)(\mathbf p+e\mathbf A)$, where $\mathbf A$ is the vector potential. I think this definition is more clear than the other.
2. Another definition is that $\mathbf J= (e/\hbar) (\partial \tilde H/\partial \mathbf k)$, where $\tilde H$ is the Bloch Hamiltonian, which is a function from BZ to the space of operators on the Hilbert space. I suspect this definition is somewhat related to the group velocity. But the unclear thing is that $\mathbf k$ is the crystal momentum, not real momentum. In this case I am not sure that the group velocity represents the movement of wavelet.

Then the lecture note asserts that the above two definitions are equivalent as follows:
[image]

Using the second definition, one easily obtains
$$\mathbf J=(e/m)(\mathbf p+\hbar \mathbf k +e\mathbf A).$$
How is this equivalent to the first definition? Also, does the second definition can be generalized to other situation? (The assumptions of Bloch theorem must be satisfied in the second definition, but the first definition is very general.)

Comment: I think it makes sense to take $k=0$ in the second definition of the current. I'm trying to figure out a rigorous way of justifying it, and one option I can think of is that the group velocity for non-zero $k$ is opposite that of $-k$, so the contributions to the current for non-zero $k$ always cancel each other out (it's not clear that this always holds though).

Comment: @Henry Shackleton Oh that can be a clue!